# Accidentally removing entity from surface

Tags: codefluent

Since some time (a few weeks or so) I am constantly removing entities from my canvas by accident. It happend to me about 8 times already. I am using Codefluent for several years now and have not had this problem before. I don't know how exactly I do it, sometimes clicking or double clicking or so does the trick. Obviously I can get the entity back on the canvas from the model but it is annoying. I have the latest version of Codefluent.

Comment: Sounds strange. Nothing was changed to the editor recently that would correspond to entity removal. Could that be related to some 3rd parties? Visual Studio is a very hostile environment where addins and package can change the behavior of others. Or keyboard shortcut (as all CodeFluent menu items and sub items are accessible by shortcuts)

Comment: I have only one plugin: Resharper...

Comment: Just happend again... Twice in a row... It has something to do with holding shift and clicking or something...

Comment: Got it! Shift + Right click on an entity and its gone...

Comment: It should display the standard CodeFluent menu. Can't reproduce at all. It really looks like some extension is doing this. You can check all the DLLs loaded into VS's process if you go to Tools/Options/CodeFluent Entities/Tools/Show CodeFluent Diagnostics and check the Loaded Assemblies property. The big issue is a lot of Microsoft or assimilated code (Xamarin, etc.) is also 3rd party with regard to VS IDE...